# What is Pixel Width?

Tags: jpeg, photo, pixel

I have been asked to have the **pixel width** of my JPEG photo between 240 to 600. However , I don't actually what **pixel width** is. I searched the whole property details and everywhere (including Google) , but none does seem to have an answer. Please tell me what it is, or at least , tell where is it specified in the properties dialog box or somewhere.

My PC: Windows 7

Thanks.

Comment: I think they mean the width of the image in pixels. 'Pixel Width' is not a term.

Comment: @Cube32 So , you mean `width` or `height` or `horizontal resolution` or `vertical resolution` ? (I'm not a techie in this field so I don't know that much)

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: just the `width` - resolution is a whole other thing :)

Comment: @GOTO0 I actually don't know where should I ask this.It would be helpful if you give the link of the Q&A site where I should ask this.Thanks.

Comment: @Cube32 Ok, that's the answer.But it's in a comment . How do I accept it ? :)

Comment: i've added it as an answer :)

Comment: SOF wants me to wait 4 minutes.....

Comment: Ok, if this is off-topic , sorry to disturb you all, but then where should I post this question next time if this not the right place? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure the person that asked meant the width of the image in pixels. 'Pixel Width' is not a proper term.

Just change the width of your image, in pixels.

Comment: And BTW , 200 pixels per inch (dpi) is equivalent to horizontal and vertical resolution , if I guess it correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that the width of your photo in pixels has to be between 240 and 600. It should not be too complicated to find this information in the properties of your file.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the intent was the width of your image in pixels should be in [240, 600], that is, within the range you stated.  This would not constrain the height in pixels.